# Как можно сделать редактор кода внутри игры на юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу написать игру на C# в Юнити, в самой игре хочу реализовать редактор кода, ну что-то вроде обучающей игры. Уже несколько дней ищу в интернете хоть какую нибудь информацию но пока нечего так и не нашел. За исключением двух платных асетов, ито не знаю подойдут ли они...
Если есть какие либо догадки буду очень благодарен.

Comment: ищи по ключевиках "c# unity runtime scripting" - найдешь что нужно довольно быстро. Вообще здесь уже были подобные вопросы и на них отвечали, тольк я сам не нашел через поиск по ру.стековерфлоу, так что тебя не виню что не искал. С меня плюс и удачи в начинаниях